# Wordpress Category Selector - stuck

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm using Auctionpress to create an ebay like website. I have over 300 categories you can list an item in.

When a user is listing an item they only get a list box with all the categories and then they have to go through them all to find the right one.

Instead of that, I want the user to first see all the top parent categories, when they select one it gets all the child categories, and so forth, until they get to the final category - just like in ebay.

like in this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljW7_JrlAL4

what I managed to do so far:

list all the categories with depth = 1  (that's the first step)

```
wp_list_categories('hide_empty=0&depth=1');
```

Ok it worked

Now I want when a user clicks a category if it has child categories a new panel next to original one becomes visible with all the child categories, and so on, untill user reaches a category that has no childs.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do an ajax call which fetches the children of the given category.
How to use Ajax in WP: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

the ajax call wil return something like:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'hide_empty'=> 0,
  'depth' => 1,
  'child_of' => $clicked_parent, //the Id of the parrent
);
wp_list_categories($args);
```

Also look at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories

Not a ready to use answer. But you'll have to figure out the details.

Comment: I need to place a category selector anywhere where first I only get the top parent categories and then i select one and see the childs.... and so on untill i get to final category.....

it's for a auction website when user is listing an item and has to choose its category

Comment: what you ask is to complicated to give you an example. Ans if you don't know Ajax you need to learn is. Do you know jquery? if so here is a good place t begin: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp